# EF 6 Database First - map stored procedure to existing objects

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

Hi I have a project which is quite old. It uses stored procedures which isn't an issue but it does have lots of error prone mapping code in old ADO.net. My main goal is to cut down the mapping more than anything. We have a separate library of I guess POCO/DTO type objects that get mapped to.

Can I map stored procedures to these classes easily. I suppose I could use AutoMapper as the mapping will be exact but I'm wondering if there's an easier way that it does out of the box. The list of complex type doesn't show the imported library's business classes. Cheers.

Comment: Did you know that Entity Framework can map to stored procedures. That will do the mapping for you. If you can use EF, I shall write up a more complete answer for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using AutoMapper, create a complex return type using "Edit Function Import", which has the exact properties as the stored procedure result.